# Происходит запрос при NOT NULL

Tags: mysql

Добрый день. У меня есть очень интересный вопрос.
В общем, почему при добавлении несуществующего значения ('') в поле с маркером NOT NULL запрос происходит и вставляет новую запись. Хотя, при этом возвращает Warning, но почему Warning, а не Fatal Error ?

Листинг:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exotichoroscopes_data` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` int(2) NOT NULL,
`zodiac` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`date_begin` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`date_end` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

В поле `type` недопустимо добавления пустого значения ! Так же как и в `name`.

Comment: У Вас не правильный MySQL :D

А какая разница, Warning или Fatal Error, хоть какую-то ошибку выводит же, сообщает Вас что что-то пошло не так. Если бы вообще ошибку не выводило, тогда уже другой разговор.

Answer (score 1):

Из документации:

> SunMicrosystems
>
> Inserting NULL into a column that has been declared NOT NULL. For multiple-row INSERT statements or INSERT INTO ... SELECT statements, the column is set to the implicit default value for the column data type. This is 0 for numeric types, the empty string ('') for string types, and the “zero” value for date and time types.

В mysql у колонок есть неявное default значение. В обычном режиме если вы вставляете несколько записей за раз и не указываете значение для NOT NULL записи, вместо NULL будет вставлено default значение.. Неявное default значение для числовых полей 0.

Вы можете поменять это поведение, установив соответствующий sql mode: [тут документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html).

Вам нужно посмотреть режим `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` и `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`. Ну или поставить `SQL_MODE` в `TRADITIONAL`.

Comment: Плохо-плохо...
Но спасибо за объяснение !